# Python Jupyter notebook throws unicode error in one instance but not another

Tags: python-3.x, string, operating-system

I know how to solve the issue (r, double \ and so on.) but it literally burns my mind and I can not understand why the following code:

```
basepath = "C:\Users\Rio\Pictures\Screenshot"
```

raises error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

while the following code (which looks identical to me) works just fine:

```
basepath = "D:\Teaching content\Poker\Zenith Poker 2020"
```

Answer (score 1):

When Python sees `"\` it tries to do a unicode escape, which is the source of the error. It depends on the character that follows `"\"`. On Windows, file paths typically contain `"\U"`, which throws off Python. When you're working with strings that contain a lot of `"\"` characters, use raw strings instead.

```
basepath = r"C:\Users\Rio\Pictures\Screenshot"
```

Or just rewrite your string with double slashes

```
basepath = "C:\\Users\\Rio\\Pictures\\Screenshot"
```

When Python sees `"\\"` it understands it as `"\"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give PATH module a shot:

use this:

```
    from pathlib import Path
    basepath = Path('put your path here ') # using either r string or '\\'
```